# Issue with Selenium and Tableau Server

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tableau-api

Trying to change a filter on tableau dashboard hosted on tableau server through selenium script.

Need to know whether there are some restrictions on tableau server or do we have any work around for the same.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("PATH Name")

dropdowmclick = driver.find_element_by_class_name("tabComboBoxName")
dropdowmclick.click()

time.sleep(20)
driver.close()
```

Require help here.

Comment: What is the purpose of using Selenium with Tableau Server?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is a browser automation tool and mimics real user actions on the page. Generally speaking, it doesn't matter what is there under test in the browser.

Just one specific note about `tableau`: since it uses AJAX a lot and different parts of a page are loaded asynchronously, you would have to use [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) a lot - avoid hardcoded time sleep intervals and explicitly wait for specific elements before interacting with them.